# Bootstrap-datetimepicker add days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When i select a "From" date then "Days" of how many days to add, how can it automatically output the date on the "To" date?

This is a picture of my project. the output of the "To" must be 06/06/2017

[image: Sample Picture]

I am using Eonasdan's Bootstrap-datetimepicker: [Link here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

This is my code:

index.chtml

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">From:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">x
        <div class="input-group date" id="dpFrom">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Days:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="txtDays" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">To:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="txtTo" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#dpFrom').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function to be called on the `onChange` event from the first date box. You pass the date as a parameter to that, then in the function add five days to that date and use jQuery to output target the end date.

Answer (score 0):

> [dp.change](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange): Fired when the date is changed.
>
> parameters:
>
> e = {
>
> ```
> date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
> oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> ```
>
> }

Using the **date** parameter contained in the event object and the moment methods [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) and [add days](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) you can write:

```js
$('#dpFrom').datetimepicker({
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
  //
  // on date change get current date and add txtDays days
  //
  var txtTo = e.date.add(+$('#txtDays').val() || 0, 'days');
  //
  // format result and save to txtDays
  //
  $('#txtTo').val(txtTo.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 control-label">From:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
        <div class="input-group date" id="dpFrom">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Days:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
        <input id="txtDays" type="text" class="form-control" value="5">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 control-label">To:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
        <input id="txtTo" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```